# Hyperref: How to start the newline label text after the CheckBox?

Tags: hyperref, bold, forms

I want to use the checkbox with text, but it should be break to a new line and start first after the checkbox at the new line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\def\LayoutCheckField#1#2{% label, field
    #2 #1%
}
\medskip
\begin{Form}
    \mbox{\CheckBox[width=10pt,height=10pt,bordercolor=0 0 0,name=terms,]{~\textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus vitae felis consectetur, ullamcorper eros hendrerit, volutpat mi. Etiam facilisis cursus mauris, vel blandit odio. Fusce at egestas nibh.}}}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Why the `\mbox` around the text?

Comment: Otherwise the label text is not in the middle besides of the checkbox.

Comment: Can you show an example of the problem you face with the alignment? The `\mbox{}` will prevent line breaks.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz You are right. thank you! I updated my question.

Comment: your example doesn't give the output in the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\LayoutCheckField` macro is precisely where you should put this formatting information. What you want to achieve is for the check box to act like the "itemize" symbol in a list, so we can do it that way

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\def\LayoutCheckField#1#2{% label, field
        \list{}{}\item[\raisebox{-3pt}{#2}] #1
        \endlist
}
\medskip
\begin{Form}
        \CheckBox[width=10pt,height=10pt,bordercolor=0 0 0,name=terms,]{\textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus vitae felis consectetur, ullamcorper eros hendrerit, volutpat mi. Etiam facilisis cursus mauris, vel blandit odio. Fusce at egestas nibh.}}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you always want the label to be bold, you can also put `\bfseries` inside the `\LayoutCheckField` definition instead of typing `\textbf` for every check box.

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you.